# What is the best way to re-use code in two different situations when it needs variables from the current scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been writing a lot of code, and I try to avoid duplicated logic a lot, but I couldn't think of a way around this case.

```
if(something){
 // do something
 // then run a lot of code
} else {
 // do something else
 // then run a lot of the same code
}
```

I tried this:

```
if(something){
 // do something
 traloc()
} else {
 // do something else
 traloc()
}

function traloc(){
 // then run a lot of code
}
```

And it was working with variables, but I couldn't call `resolve` or `reject` from within the function, which means it doesn't inherit the function variables of the scope it's called in, and only some variables?

So to really achieve perfection I'd need to do:

```
if(something){
 // do something
 traloc(var1, var2, var3, var4)
} else {
 // do something else
 traloc(var1, var2, var3, var4)
}

function traloc(var1, var2, var3, var4){
 // then run a lot of code
}
```

Is there a better way to abstract logic into functioning snippets that inherit function scope?

This is the real code for when I need to pass variables resolve and reject instead of having access to them

```
function relateRe(thing, relations, relation, relative, commonStateHash){
    /** params
     *  @param thing is the thing we are saving relations for
     *  @param relations is a list of relationships we are saving
     *  @param relation will be a @type {Number} representing the index of the relationship string, ie: the property of thing that is a list of related things
     *  @param relative will be a @type {Number} representing the property of the related thing where the _id of the thing should be inserted
     *  @param commonStateHash is the common hash used to identify backup states from this save function
     */
    /** returns a promise that resolves to:
     *  @func success 
     *    @var thingRelatedFully
     *  @func failure
     *    @var thingRelatedSemi
     *    @var err
     */
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      /** store a backup state of the relative for use if any other saving fails
       *  also handles conversion of non-registered documents into ._id bearing saveable model objects
       *  also handles conversion of non-object, ObjectId type relatives to ._id bearing saveable model objects
       */
      console.log(thing)
      console.log('relations')
      console.log(relations)
      console.log('relation')
      console.log(relation)
      console.log('relative')
      console.log(relative)
      if(!thing[relations[relation].relationship][relative]){
        /** check if we continue updating relationships
         */
          continueRelatingOrResolve(thing, relations, relation, relative, commonStateHash, resolve, reject)

      } else {
        makeBackupState(thing[relations[relation].relationship][relative], relations, commonStateHash)
            .then((thingRelative, err)=>{
              if(!err){
                console.log(thingRelative)
                thing[relations[relation].relationship][relative] = thingRelative
                // thingRelative = thing[relations[relation].relationship][relative]
                /** add the _id of the given thing to the relationships list of the current relative
                 */
                  smartOpts.pushOpt(thing._id, relative[relations[relation].property])
                let relativeRelations = createRelativeRelations(relations, relation)
                let optsRelative = {
                  thing: thingRelative,
                  relations: relativeRelations,
                  save: relations[relation],
                  commonStateHash: commonStateHash,
                  backupState: false
                }
                saveThing(optsRelative)
                  .then((thingRelativeSaved, err)=>{
                    if(!err){
                      /** check if we continue updating relationships
                       */
                        continueRelatingOrResolve(thing, relations, relation, relative, commonStateHash, resolve, reject)
                    } else {
                      resolve(thing, err)
                    }
                  })
              } else {
                resolve(thing, err)
              }
            })
      }
    })

    function continueRelatingOrResolve(thing, relations, relation, relative, commonStateHash, resolve, reject){
      /** if the current relation is not the last of this relationship group/list
       *  increment the relationship counter
       *  update the next relationship
       */
        if((relative < thing[relations[relation].relationship].length-1) && ((relations[relation].save && (thing.stateId == commonStateHash)) || relations[relation].upsert)){
          console.log('next relative in relationship %s', relation)
          relateRe(thing, relations, relation, relative+=1, commonStateHash)
            .then((thing, err)=>{
              if(!err){
                resolve(thing)
              } else {
                resolve(thing, err)                                                    
              }
            })
        } 
      /** otherwise if the current relationship group/list is not the last group/list
       *  increment the relationship group/list counter
       *  update the next relationship
       */
        else if(relation < relations.length-1){
          console.log('next relationship in relationship %s', relation+1)                          
          relateRe(thing, relations, relation+=1, 0, commonStateHash)
            .then((thing, err)=>{
              if(!err){
                resolve(thing)
              } else {
                resolve(thing, err)                                                    
              }
            })
        } 
      /** otherwise if that was the last relationship and the last relationship group
       *  resolve the current state of the thing
       */
        else {
          console.log("resolving due to last relationship")
          resolve(thing)
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: sorry yeah beat you to it ;)

Comment: should comment the comments but..

Comment: well you either pass them or you make them global or you put the function inside the function, or you pass in a reference if they are properties of it. Hard to tell what you can do with a generic snipplet.

Comment: Make a local function with the shared logic and either directly access parent scope variables or pass some variables to it.  If the local function is declared in that scope, it can access the same variables.  This is just a classic way of handling a programming where you want to run largely the same functionality in more than one place.  Make a function and call it from multiple places.

Comment: @jfriend00 I did declare the function within the other function but it doesn't seem to inherit resolve and reject variables?

Comment: Well, please edit your question to describe the ACTUAL problem you had and show us the ACTUAL code.  The code you currently show has no `resolve` in it so we can't see the problem you have and can't help you solve it.  You are obviously doing something wrong in how you try to make the local function, but without seeing real code, we can't advise what that is.

Comment: There are lots of design ideas, but they all apply to specific problems. You could pass a single object to your function, you could use some sort of polymorphism, where each object has it's own 'do something', maybe there's an object composition solution. But the question it just too broad — it's pretty close to, 'how do you design software'.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry okay I added it, I understand

Comment: So, in the real code what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Also, this code is full of the promise anti-pattern where you wrap existing promises with a new outer promise.  That is not necessary.  You can just return and chain internal promises.

Comment: When I run continueRelatingOrResolve(thing, relations, relation, relative, commonStateHash, resolve, reject) I need to pass resolve and reject, it doesn't seem to inherit them.

Umm I see so you return the .then. I don't really like using the return style coding, resolving is easier to follow imo

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to sort out your code and figure out the correct way to write the code, but I'm running into a bunch of programming mistakes:

1. You're using an anti-pattern of wrapping inner promises with a manually created new promise and then trying to call `resolve()` and `reject()` at the right time.  You should just return inner promises from the function and return inner promises from within `.then()` handlers to chain them.
2. You're expecting two arguments to a `.then((thingRelative, err)=>{` handler.  That never happens.  `.then()` handlers are passed one argument.  Errors are rejected promises which you get with `.catch()`.
3. You're attempting to pass multiple arguments to `resolve()` as in `resolve(thing, err)`.  You can't do that either.  Both `resolve()` and `reject()` take exactly one argument.
4. You appear to be eating all errors and just calling `resolve()`.  Do you really want to never return an error of any kind.  I honestly can't tell what you really should be doing with errors.  Calling `resolve(thing, err)` just does `resolve(thing)` so that's how I've coded below, but somehow I doubt that it actually desirable.
5. The fact that you have `relateRe()` which calls `continueRelatingOrResolve()` which calls `relateRe()` which calls `continueRelatingOrResolve()` makes this code very difficult to sort out what it does and prone to all sorts of possible errors.  I can't follow what this incestuous relationship is supposed to be doing so I can't suggest a better way to do things, but you'd usually rather have A calling B and C rather or even B sometimes calling itself rather than A calling B and B calling A.  Probably some better way of structuring the code would make this a lot easier to follow.

Anyway, when removing the anti-pattern, attempting to simplify your code and guessing on some things you just had wrong, here's what I get:

```
// always returns a promise so caller can know when it's done
// promise can resolve or reject if there's an unrecoverable error
function relateRe(thing, relations, relation, relative, commonStateHash) {
    if (!thing[relations[relation].relationship][relative]) {
        // check if we continue updating relationships
        // make sure we always return a promise
        return Promise.resolve(continueRelatingOrResolve(thing, relations, relation, relative, commonStateHash));

    } else {
        return makeBackupState(thing[relations[relation].relationship][relative], relations, commonStateHash)
            .then(thingRelative => {
                console.log(thingRelative);
                thing[relations[relation].relationship][relative] = thingRelative;
                /** add the _id of the given thing to the relationships list of the current relative  */
                smartOpts.pushOpt(thing._id, relative[relations[relation].property]);
                let relativeRelations = createRelativeRelations(relations, relation);
                let optsRelative = {
                    thing: thingRelative,
                    relations: relativeRelations,
                    save: relations[relation],
                    commonStateHash: commonStateHash,
                    backupState: false
                };
                return saveThing(optsRelative).then(thingRelativeSaved => {
                    /** check if we continue updating relationships
                     */
                    return continueRelatingOrResolve(thing, relations, relation, relative, commonStateHash);
                }).catch(err => {
                    // it appears that your original code does not want to return errors at all
                    // and is just resolving with thing so that's what this does, though it does not
                    // seem like a good thing to just eat all errors
                    return thing;
                });
            });
    }
}

function continueRelatingOrResolve(thing, relations, relation, relative, commonStateHash) {
    /** if the current relation is not the last of this relationship group/list
     *  increment the relationship counter
     *  update the next relationship
     */
    if ((relative < thing[relations[relation].relationship].length - 1) && 
          ((relations[relation].save && (thing.stateId == commonStateHash)) || 
          relations[relation].upsert)) {
        console.log('next relative in relationship %s', relation);
        return relateRe(thing, relations, relation, relative += 1, commonStateHash);
        /** otherwise if the current relationship group/list is not the last group/list
         *  increment the relationship group/list counter
         *  update the next relationship
         */
    } else if (relation < relations.length - 1) {
        console.log('next relationship in relationship %s', relation + 1);
        return relateRe(thing, relations, relation += 1, 0, commonStateHash);
    }
    /** otherwise if that was the last relationship and the last relationship group
     *  resolve the current state of the thing
     */
    else {
        console.log("resolving due to last relationship");
        return thing;
    }
}
```

I do not expect this to work out of the box since I have no way of running it and no spec to go by for what this is supposed to do or what the data structures look like, but hopefully you can learn from the structure and see how nested async operations can be coded without the anti-pattern.

And, since there's no `resolve` or `reject` being passed around at all, that original problem is gone.  I'm guessing it was caused by the structure you had where A calls B which calls A which calls B which calls A, etc... and trying to keep track of which resolve and reject is which, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @JDoe - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark next to the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write

```
if (something) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
// then run a lot of code
```

Comment: sorry that you got a downvote but have a look at my edited post, I've included the real state that this logic happens